# Dynamic NavigationController with UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm making an app that is controlled by a UITabBarController, and I want to show a different navigation bar with each view. The problem is that my updates have no affect.

In AppDelegate, I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

HomeTabController *vc = [[HomeTabController alloc] init];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

This is my HomeTabController, which extends `UITabBarController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// FirstViewController
HomeController *fvc=[[HomeController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
fvc.title=@"Store";
fvc.tabBarItem.image = [self resize_image:@"Bank" newSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];

//SecondViewController
ViewProfileController *svc=[[ViewProfileController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
svc.title=@"Profile";
svc.tabBarItem.image = [self resize_image:@"Contacts" newSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];

self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc, svc, nil];

}
```

Here is ViewProfileController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Profile";

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
sw = screenRect.size.width;
sh = screenRect.size.height;

nh = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
ny = nh + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y;

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,ny,sw,sh-ny) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
UIBarButtonItem *edit_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(nav_edit_profile)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = edit_btn;
}
```

When I run the app, the tab bar is created properly, and I can navigate between both views without error. However, the NavigationBar is empty, with no title or edit button.

The code works fine if this view takes initial control in AppDelegate, instead of HomeTabController.

How do I edit the navigation bar when using a UITabBarController?

I thought I might just have to set the views reference: `fvc.navigationController = self.navigationController;` but it says the navigationController is readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Storyboards for this. It will simplify the process and let you visually see what is happening. Your storyboard will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPWQh.png).

Then, you do not need to add any code at all in the AppDelegate and you can use the ViewControllers normally. If you want to call the navigation controller for a specific view controller from that view controller, call `self.navigationController`.

Comment: Thanx but I would prefer a code solution, I can't stand the visual editors. I am already calling `self.navigationController` and getting proper size values from it, but none of my updates effect the navigation bar.

Comment: My apps UI changed, so I no longer had to solve this issue. But it probably had to do with a storyboard setting somewhere. The app was a hybrid storyboard/straight code app, so I probably could have solved it with more storyboards

Answer (score 0):

UITabbarController is not designed to be inside UINavigationController. so your code should be as follow:

```
self.window.rootViewController = yourTabbarControllr;
```

and why do you this in view did load:

```
HomeController *fvc=[[HomeController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

are you trying to create another tabbar in side current tabbar?

**edit:**
here is an example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    HomeTabController *tabController = [[HomeTabController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.myViewController1 = [[myViewController1 alloc] init];
    self.myViewController2 = [[myViewController2 alloc] init];
    self.myViewController3 = [[myViewController3 alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myViewController1];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myViewController2];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myViewController3];

    tabController.viewControllers = @[nav1, nav2, nav3];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: HomeController is a `UIViewController`, HomeTabController is a `UITabBarController`.. sorry for the confusing names - I have actually renamed HomeController to StoreController in my code.

Comment: I tried the first edit and created a NavigationController in HomeTabController instead of in AppDelegate, and nothing broke, but viewDidLoad is no longer getting called for any of my views